# Is it safe to declare a mutex at file-scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I realize [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475588/is-it-safe-to-declare-a-mutex-as-a-static-file-scoped-variable) is similar, but mine is not specific to Windows.

Is is safe and good form to declare a mutex at file-scope like so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include "Logger.h"

mutex my_mutex;

void Logger::log()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 29; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: *I want to synchronize at instance-level, not across instances.* Then the mutex should be a non-static data member of the `Logger` class. The global mutex you have right now does exactly what you say you **don't** want done.

Comment: To ensure file-scope use `static` to declare your mutex. Problem: *file-scope* is antinomic with *instance-level*; what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Edited the question. I understand that my code will sync across instances. This is ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truly limit this to file scope in a modern C++ style:

```
namespace {
   mutex my_mutex;
   <information to protect goes here>
}
```

Then the answer is, "yes it is safe".

In your case, however, it appears that you are attempting to protect std::cout.   Since cout is not limited to your file scope, your mutex is not going to do much good unless you can guarantee that this is the only use of cout and/or cerr in the entire program.